# Custom Alertdialog In Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I've tried to change the color of text and background in Alertdialog to white text and transparent background. However, it didn't work.

Please refer to below and let me know what did I miss. Thank you.

Note: Android with Kotlin

*** 1. Code in Main Activity ***
[image]

*** 2. Style.xml ***

[image]

*** 3. Simulation Outcome ***
[image]

*** 4. What I want to is ***
[image]

Comment: What do you want to have as output?

Comment: @MMC / I'd like to see white color text and transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transparent dialog, you need to set `android:background`  change your style like

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<style name="myAlertdialogstyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> 
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item> 
       <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: At the first time, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work for me. so edited a little bit, based on yours, then It works as below stated. Your suggestion was very helpful. Thanks a lot.
------------------------------------------------------------------


<style name="myAlertdialogstyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

`<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"> <item name="android:background">@color/Black</item> <item name="colorAccent">@color/White</item> </style>`
Here android:Background is android property so it will automatically reflect to your dialog
also you should use Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert instead of Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog